AWS Step Function: Terminating nested workflows
I have a AWS step function defined in the C# CDK where one of the states is a task as defined as such:
var executeGlueJobStepFunction = new CustomState(this, "ExecuteGlueJobStepFunction", new CustomStateProps
{
    StateJson = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Type", "Task" },
            { "Resource", "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2" },
            { "Parameters", new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "StateMachineArn.$", JsonPath.Format($"arn:aws:states:{Stack.Of(this).Region}:{Stack.Of(this).Account}:stateMachine:{{}}", JsonPath.StringAt("$.stepFunctionName")) },
                    { "Input.$", JsonPath.EntirePayload }
                }
            },
            { "ResultSelector", new Dictionary<string,object>
                {
                    { "Output.$", "$.Output" }
                }
            },
        },
});

This starts executing another step function that triggers a glue job run synchronously.
Now, when the caller step function fails or is aborted, the child execution (and the glue job run) continues to completion.
Is there a way I can change this behaviour so that the child execution and glue job run are terminated if the caller step function fails?

When dealing with nested Step Functions executions, adding StopNewExecution: true to the Parameters solved this issue. Here's how you can try to modify the CDK code:
var executeGlueJobStepFunction = new CustomState(this, "ExecuteGlueJobStepFunction", new CustomStateProps
{
    StateJson = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Type", "Task" },
        { "Resource", "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2" },
        { "Parameters", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "StateMachineArn.$", JsonPath.Format($"arn:aws:states:{Stack.Of(this).Region}:{Stack.Of(this).Account}:stateMachine:{{}}", JsonPath.StringAt("$.stepFunctionName")) },
                { "Input.$", JsonPath.EntirePayload },
                { "StopNewExecution", true }  // This parameter does the trick
            }
        },
        { "ResultSelector", new Dictionary<string,object>
            {
                { "Output.$", "$.Output" }
            }
        },
    },
});

Just be aware there might be a slight delay between the parent stopping and the child execution/Glue job terminating. This worked perfectly in our production environment.
Let me know how it goes.
